# using in-memory data-structures

Tags: in-memory-database

I have a client requirement of 
not to use an RDBMS, but instead do everything using in-memory data-structures   If the server is restarted then the application state will revert to the last state saved.

I don't have any idea of using in-memory data , I used to work with MySQL ,but not in memory
If anyone could please guide me a bit about this , any tutorial or something

Below are some examples ...

```
     public Object save(Object object, Class c) {
    database.ofy().put(object);
    return object;
}

public void delete(Long id, Class c) {

    database.ofy().delete(c, id);   
}

public Object findById(String id, Class c) {
    return database.ofy().find(c, id);
}

public Iterable<Object> findAll(Class c) {
    Iterable<Object> models = database.ofy().query(c).fetch();
    return models;

    }
```

}

Thanks

Comment: what do you mean in-memory? please clarify your question.

Comment: means not using actual SQL,like i will not save any data by going to SQL and saving values,all the records will be saved retrieved, delete programatically and the changes will be in memory,NOT in SQL,Not using any database .. no sql,oracle etc

Comment: I think he probably meant one of [those](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In-memory_database). Anyways, could you please provide more info on the task, what other requirements do you have apart from handling some data in-memory? What is your tech stack? Do you need to perform real-time data back-up? Are you willing to pay or preffer an open-source solution etc?

Comment: i have edited my question , one example could be by using objectify

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use [sqlite](http://www.sqlite.org/), which has hooks to a lot of languages.

the default use for sqlite is for file-based, but it can easily be used [in-memory](http://www.sqlite.org/inmemorydb.html).

Comment: does it support  the application state to revert to the last state saved

Comment: it has transactions, if that's what you mean.